# How to put a default value (http://) on URL textbox in TinyMCE?

Tags: url, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and when i click on Insert/Edit Link, it will pop out a windows with URL, Text to Display and Target.

I want the URL textbox to have a default value of http://

I tried to use tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("http"); but nothing appear. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, **tinymce** is using `<textarea>` right? Why don't you do this :

```
<textarea>http://</textarea>
```

Comment: where shall i put this?

Comment: The Url textarea is provided by TinyMCE  by default.